# Let $S$ be a non empty subset of $\Bbb R$ and bounded above and $M=\sup S$.Then prove that either $M \in S$ or $M$ is a limit point of $S$.

Tags: real-analysis

I tried the math but I am stuck at the point that how to show that $M \in S$. I did the part that $M$ is a limit point of $S$.
$M=SupS$.Let $M$ does not belong to $S$. $M=sup s$
So $x<M$ for all x belongs to S. And for any epsilon>0,there exists a y belongs to S such that (M- epsilon)<y<M implies that (M-epsilon)<y<(M+epsilon) .Implies that M is a limit point of S.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M = \sup S$.

Case 1: $M \in S$. Then we are done.

Case 2: $M \notin S$. For each $n \in \mathbb N$ there is $a_n \in S$ such that $a_n > M - \frac{1}{n}$.

Hence $ M - \frac{1}{n} <a_n \le M <  M + \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$.

With $n \to \infty$ we get $a_n \to M$.